# Need help with a flowchart

Tags: c++, flowchart

I need help with a flowchart in a question I'm doing. I've completed the programming code but just have no idea on flowcharts if anyone can give me an idea on how to do this then I'll appreciate it. This is the question:

Write a C++ program that reads from keyboard 3 integers, with proper input prompt, and then displays the maximum sum of any pair of numbers from these three. If the 3 numbers are 5, 6 and 7 for instance, then the maximum sum comes from 6+7=13. Draw the flowchart of this C++ program, and also desk check the program for the three input integers 12, 3 and 7, or a different set of 3 numbers which will make the desk checking less trivial within your program design.

I've completed the code which is:

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, num3, sum;

    cout << "Enter number ";
    cin >> num1;

    cout << "Enter number ";
    cin >> num2;

    cout << "Enter number ";
    cin >> num3;

   /* if(num1 >= num2)
    {


    }*/

    if(num1 > num2 && num3 >
     num2)
    {
            sum = num1 +  num3; 
            cout << "The sum of " << num1 << " and " << num3 << " = " << sum << endl;
    }
    else if(num1 >= num3 && num2 >= num3)
    {
         sum = num1 + num2;         
         cout << "The sum of " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " = " << sum << endl; 
    }
    else if (num2 >= num1 && num3 >= num1)
   {
        sum = num2 + num3; 
        cout << "The sum of " << num2 << " and " << num3 << " = " << sum << endl;
    } 
  //else
  //{
    //  cout << "all three numbers must be diffrent" <<endl;
     // }

     system("PAUSE");

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read about [Flowcharts](http://www.nos.org/htm/basic2.htm). If you do not know about Flowcharting how will you make one.

Answer (score 0):

Read about flowcharts , see the flowcharts at http://www.edrawsoft.com/flowchart-examples.php , and conceptulaize your own.

Answer (score -1):

Read up on [state machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). This will help you map out the behavior of your program and to create the necessary flow charts. :)

Comment: -1 State charts and flow charts are two entirely different beasts. It would be silly to model the OP's program with a statechart. In what way is this program stateful?